# Problemas com recursividade - Muito gasto de memória - Angular 9 - SetTimeOut()

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, memória

Galera, estou montando uma API e preciso fazer solicitações a cada três segundos no servidor.

Segue o código:

```
countAcess() {
    if (this.menuExa && this.appService.requestValid()) {
      this.appService.getCountg()
        .subscribe(
          data => {
            if (data) {
              this.monitor.userc = data;
            }
          });
    }
    clearTimeout(this.setTimeVerific);
    this.setTimeVerific = setTimeout(valida => { this.countAcess(); }, 2500);
  }
```

Meu problema é a memória, encheu 16GB de RAM em cerca de 8/10 horas, vai travar qualquer máquina. Como posso fazer para esvaziar essa memória ou até gastar menos? Sei que é isso pois, se desativo a função `SetTimeOut()`, a memória não infla o consumo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Esse `subscribe` deve ter um `unsubscribe`. Isso é prática comum noutras bibliotecas [mas também em Angular](https://angular.io/guide/observables). Ou seja, invocar o `subscribe` retorna uma callback para poder fazer `unsubscribe`, e assim no inicio dessa função `countAcess` seria bom fazer unsubscribe da anterior para não acumular novas subscrições e encher a memória.

Seria algo assim:

```
countAcess(unsubscribe) {
  if (this.menuExa && this.appService.requestValid()) {
    if (unsubscribe) unsubscribe();
    unsubscribe = this.appService.getCountg()
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          if (data) {
            this.monitor.userc = data;
          }
        });
  }
  clearTimeout(this.setTimeVerific);
  this.setTimeVerific = setTimeout(valida => {
    this.countAcess(unsubscribe);
  }, 2500);
}
```

A ideia é ter sempre acessível o ultimo `unsubscribe` para poder ser chamado antes de fazer um novo `subscribe` e assim libertar memória.

Comment: Amigo, era isso mesmo! Obrigado peça resposta